# In BMS if I connect li ion batteries of different capacities, how much mA will it provide in the output?

Tags: batteries, bms

If I connect one 1200mah, one 2600 mah and one 800mah li ion battery with a 3S BMS board. How much mA will it provide at the output? And when the BMS will stop giving output?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Series or parallel? Series = 800mAh total. Parallel = 4600mAh total. Not a good idea but series is worse than parallel.

Comment: @DKNguyen OP wrote "3S BMS" implying serial.

Comment: mA? whatever you demand, up until the BMS overcurrent trip. mAh? that of the smallest battery before the cell-level undervoltage trip.

Comment: If a single battery is discharged and other two are not fully discharged will the BMS still give output?